# Make a row in angular chantt chart clickable

Tags: angularjs, charts, row, clickable

I have downloaded the demo at https://www.angular-gantt.com/demo/

But, how can I make a row clickable and redirect to another webpage, please?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you should add to each attribute you want to click with ng-click in the element head.

You can see angular ref. on ngClick [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

So as you did not specify where you are loading your destination you want each click to point to (static, result of function or array element) this is all I can say.

So your each element should look like

```
<element ng-click="destination or {{angular expression}}">

element content

</element>
```